# No matching distribution found for torch==1.5.0

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

this error occurred

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.5.0 (from versions: 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.5.0
```

then I tried to solve it by the command

```
pip install torch==1.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

and then I tried to execute the command again ..

```
pip install -r C:\Bachelor\urban-sound-tagging-master\requirements.txt
```

the same error occurred

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.5.0 (from versions: 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.5.0
```

what can I do ?

Comment: what do you have in `requirements.txt`?  Maybe there is `torch==1.5.0` and you have to remove it

Comment: Some PyTorch version only comes with a specific version of Python. You are probably using some 3.x Python, which only supports 1.7.0 and above. Try downgrading your Python version.

Comment: Do you need/want a specific version of PyTorch? Are you trying to install 1.5.0 specifically?

Answer (score -1):

You can install PyTorch previous versions from this link [PyTorch previous versions](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/)

Example:

CUDA 9.2

```
conda install pytorch==1.5.0 torchvision==0.6.0 cudatoolkit=9.2 -c pytorch
```

CUDA 10.1

```
conda install pytorch==1.5.0 torchvision==0.6.0 cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

CUDA 10.2

```
conda install pytorch==1.5.0 torchvision==0.6.0 cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

CPU Only

```
conda install pytorch==1.5.0 torchvision==0.6.0 cpuonly -c pytorch
```

Comment: They should be available via pip too (as the asker tried), not just conda. Also it's not at all clear they they actually want 1.5.0 specifically.

Comment: The first error is asking for version 1.5.0. That's why the user went with 1.7.0 hoping atleast this would work.